# The default order of /D in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

My company has a old batch file, which has this line:

```
for /D %%i in (*) do call ..\ArchiveFeedFolder.bat %%i
```

From our log, looks like windows always order the directories alphabetically by default.

for example, say I have following folders in my directory:

20150101

20150102

20150103

Above batch command will always handle 20150101, and then 20150102 and then 20150103. Is it guaranteed to work this way? I tried to find some documents, but seems no document mentioning the sorting order of

```
for /D
```

Comment: From experience (but without explicitly testing it) I agree that it seems to do this, but I can't remember seeing it documented (but I've not gone hunting).  If you need a stronger guarantee than "it seems to work", you could try `for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b/ad/on *') do ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although, as you pointed out, the sorting order in `for /d` is undocumented and, as Mofi points out in the comments, doesn't always order by name, but in an NTFS filesystem (which windows most of the times is) it does. However, if you want to be absolutely certain it always sorts by name, you should be able to use this instead of your old version:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /a:d /o:n "*"') do call ..\ArchiveFeedFolder.bat %%i
```

the `/o:n` forces this to sort by name. Fore more information about this, see [for /d](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) and [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)

I would also like to note that you call your ArchiveFeedFolder.bat with an unquoted argument, which will cause it to break if your foldernames contain spaces. I would use `do call ..\ArchiveFeedFolder.bat "%%i"` and inside your ArchiveFeedFolder.bat use `%~1%` instead of `%1`. When you then for instance copy a folder, make sure you quote it again, so `copy "%~1" "someOtherFolder"` instead of `copy %1 someOtherFolder`

Comment: It depends on the file system. NTFS returns a list of directories/files matching a pattern always sorted alphabetically. But FAT16, FAT32 and exFAT (and perhaps other file systems as well) return the list of files/directories matching a pattern in order as stored in allocation table which means not sorted by name. Using command __DIR__ with `/o:n` is definitely a good solution to get the directory/file names guaranteed sorted by name. By the way: The colon in `/a:d` and `/o:n` is optional.

Comment: @Mofi thanks, wasn't sure about the ordering. The optional colon I knew, I just think it's clearer.

Comment: Yep, `DIR /B /O:N` is the way to go, as long as there are no Unicode characters in the names that are outside the current code page.